# use dates in x axis graphview library

Tags: android

if we have date as one of the datapoint then on using tab listerner it is showing date in long format how to show it in dd/mm/yy format

Tap Listener is below :

```
series1.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
            double pointX = dataPoint.getX();
            Double d = new Double(pointX);
            int pointXX = d.intValue();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pointXX+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SimpleDateFormat.

```
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(context, new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")));
```